# Extract DynamoDB table data into Google Cloud Platform using boto3 - Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to use extract DynamoDB table data into GCP using boto3 and have 2 questions. Specifically I am utilizing the `export_table_to_point_in_time` boto3 function [Link](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb/client/export_table_to_point_in_time.html).

1. Can I extract DynamoDB table data directly into a Google Cloud Storage bucket with `export_table_to_point_in_time` or can I only extract DynamoDB table data into an S3 bucket?
2. Is it possible to extract DynamoDB data directly into a GCP BigQuery table using Python?

I've successfully extracted a DynamoDB table into an S3 bucket using boto3 and `export_table_to_point_in_time`. However, I wanted to see if it's possible to simplify my data pipeline from DynamoDB to BigQuery.

**Current Pipeline:**

DynamoDB Table -> S3 Bucket -> GCS Bucket -> BigQuery Table

**Is a pipeline like below possible?:**

DynamoDB Table -> GCS Bucket -> BigQuery Table

or

DynamoDB Table -> BigQuery Table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I extract DynamoDB table data directly into a Google Cloud Storage bucket with export_table_to_point_in_time or can I only extract DynamoDB table data into an S3 bucket?

Only into S3 buckets, external sources are not supported today.

> Is it possible to extract DynamoDB data directly into a GCP BigQuery table using Python?

You can do so using Glue ETL job if it is a large amount of data, or using Boto3 `Scan` and write to BigQuery as you normally do.

My proposed solution would be:

`DynamoDB <-- AWS Glue --> BigQuery`

Comment: Sorry, sent comment too soon:

Comment: Thank you Lee!

My tables are pretty small and the process will be an incremental load every 1hr so I may use `Scan`. I would love your thoughts on my below idea

I was thinking of doing the following:
1. A full load of the BigQuery table using `Scan` on a DynamoDB table

2. On the next run of the pipeline job, retrieve the latest timestamp values from the BQ table

3. Use the latest timestamp in combination with `Scan` and `FilterExpression` to retrieve only new records from the DynamoDB table

4. Load new records into BQ table

5. Continue in loop forever

Comment: Why not continuously write to BigTable from AWS Lambda which consumes updates from DynamoDB Streams? That way BigQuery is more up to date and you save costs and complexity.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are limited to only using BigQuery so BigTable is not an option. With that limitation being brought forward, does my comment above seem like a good solution?

Comment: Typo on my side, I meant BigQuery. My suggestion remains the same.